# PHP - Laravel check for first login globally

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to modify Laravel, so it will check whether or not the logged in user have logged in before or not, no matter what page they will navigate to on their first login.

At the moment, I can only get it to work if the user is redirected to `"/home"` on the first login:

`UserController.php`:

```
   public function index()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        if (!$user->last_login){
             //This will redirect the user to the onboarding area, if they haven't logged in before.
             return redirect()->route('onboarding');

        }else{

            if ($user->isAdmin()) {
                return view('pages.admin.home');
            }

            return view('pages.user.home');
        }
    }
public function onboarding(){
    //If the user hasn't logged in yet, let's onboard him/her
    //Please check function index(), for the actual redirect.
    return view('onboarding.home');
}
```

`routes/Web.php`:

```
//Onboarding
    Route::get('/onboarding', 'UserController@Onboarding')->name('onboarding');
```

Now as said, it will only redirect if the user navigates to `"/home"`, however if the user decides to go to for example `"/profile"`, he/she will not be redirected to `"/onboarding"`.

Where is the most appropriate place to check globally (no matter what url on my website), if it's the users first login, he/she should be redirected to `"/onboarding"`?

Comment: you have to create a log manager table where the registered user history will be noted as it goes and get the sql count query to get the details of a particular user and use that flag as a condition to determine where to go .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like it would make sense to do as a middleware that checks every request. Something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfFirstLogin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        if (!$user->last_login){
             //This will redirect the user to the onboarding area, if they haven't logged in before.
             return redirect()->route('onboarding');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

In your `Kernel.php` you will need to register the route:

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // ...
    'onboarding' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfFirstLogin::class,
    // ...
];
```

You can then wrap all routes that apply to it with a `Route::group`. You will need to make sure any routes such as login or the `onboarding` route itself need to live outside of this `Route::group`.

```
Route::get('/onboarding', 'UserController@Onboarding')->name('onboarding');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['onboarding']], function () {
    // all routes will go here.
}
```

Comment: Using above approach, I get an infinite redirect issue again. I have registered the '/onboarding' route under above middleware group.

Comment: Or maybe I should ask: how to register the `/onboarding` route correctly?

Comment: You need to keep the onboarding route outside of this middleware group. I will update my answer to include that

Comment: Thanks Alex! But how should the onboarding route be specified? I mean what "action" should it refer to?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by what "action" should it refer to, it should work with the route and controller you currently have setup.